# Safely move/archive Rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sqltransaction

I have this SQL-script/sp

```
    BEGIN TRAN
    BEGIN TRY
      INSERT INTO TblDest
      SELECT * FROM TblSource
      DELETE FROM TblSource
      COMMIT TRAN
    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
       ROLLBACK TRAN
    END CATCH
```

It moves all rows in TblSource to TblDest. I want to make sure that any rows that is inserted while this backup is done stays in TblSource.

If I set a breakpoint before the DELETE-line and opens another window and inserts a new Row in TestSource, then complete the script, the new rows is being deleted.

Do I need a Temp-table or can I lock the entire table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `HOLDLOCK` hint:

```
INSERT INTO TblDest
      SELECT * FROM TblSource WITH (HOLDLOCK)
      DELETE FROM TblSource
```

> **HOLDLOCK** Is equivalent to SERIALIZABLE.  HOLDLOCK applies only to the table
>   or view for which it is specified and only for the duration of the
>   transaction defined by the statement that it is used in. HOLDLOCK
>   cannot be used in a SELECT statement that includes the FOR BROWSE
>   option.

From MSDN: [Table hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 1):

You can try like below query.

```
  BEGIN TRAN
        BEGIN TRY
          INSERT INTO TblDest SELECT * FROM TblSource
          DELETE FROM TblSource where [SomeId] in (select id from TblDest)
          COMMIT TRAN
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
           ROLLBACK TRAN
        END CATCH
```

Comment: Thanks! I dont know which solution is the best, perhaps voting or more comments will help me. I chosed Ricardos solution in the end to avoid one more select. Probably it doesnt matter in my case, but its only possible to select one as "correct"

Comment: ...and the real "TblDest" is our archive table and is pretty massive now